# material ui react js Button text is not showing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

import React from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const MaterialOne = () =>{
return(
<>
find
</>
)
}
export default MaterialOne;

Comment: where have you used the button?

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the button code to your component. Try this code

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const MaterialOne = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Find
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default MaterialOne;
```

Codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-moore-l2h4h)

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react"; 
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

const MaterialOne = () =>{
    return( <Button> find </Button> ) 
} 

export default MaterialOne;
```